# Как программно изменить качество получаемого видео в android на среднее?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Согласно этой странице https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/c... я могу отправить "в камеру" некоторые инструкции, такие как:

> MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT - This setting requires a Uri specifying a
>   path and file name where you'd like to save the video. This setting is
>   optional but strongly recommended. If you do not specify this value,
>   the Camera application saves the requested video in the default
>   location with a default name, specified in the returned intent's
>   Intent.getData() field. MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY - This value
>   can be 0 for lowest quality and smallest file size or 1 for highest
>   quality and larger file size. MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT - Set
>   this value to limit the length, in seconds, of the video being
>   captured. MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT - Set this value to limit the
>   file size, in bytes, of the video being captured.

Я попытался использовать 1 из параметров (`MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY`):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

и это ооочень странный параметр. 
Во-первых, он не только меняет разрешение на минимальное, но и изменяет получаемое соотношение до 4:3. 
Во-вторых, получаемое 15-и секундное изображение весит ~300-500 кб, когда как его совершенно аналогичный собрат без этого параметра - 30 МБ. Это явный перебор.

Мне не надо 30 МБ видео (т.к. его предстоит еще отправить по сети, скорее всего чаще через мобильное соединение), но и 0.3 МБ - явный перебор. Параметр 0.5 воспринимается камерой как 0 (да и не описана такая возможность.

PS Да, видео уже ограничено по времени - 15 секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по документации всего 2 значения может быть передано, либо 0, либо 1. Все остальное не восприметься. Смотреть [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html?hl=ru#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY)

> EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY
>
> Added in API level 3 String EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY The name of the
>   Intent-extra used to control the quality of a recorded video. This is
>   an integer property. Currently value 0 means low quality, suitable for
>   MMS messages, and value 1 means high quality. In the future other
>   quality levels may be added.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.videoQuality"

Потому, получаеться, что это возможно только програмным способом декодировать видео, что по собственному опыту, не очень удачная мысль. Обычно занимает много времени и "жрет" много батареи. Так что по сути, остаеться только выбор между:

1. использовать батарею пользователя на ковертацию видео
2. использовать батарею на передачу видео
3. довольствоваться размером видео в "low quality"

Comment: а почему это не самая удачная идея (конвертировать)?

Comment: Во первых - ограничение версии андроид ( 4.3 базовые вещи ), во вторых -> слишком большое потребление батареи

Comment: @upward в каком смысле?